# c++ new/delete and char *

Tags: c++, char, new-operator

Can anyone help me, why I'm getting an error message while trying to free the allocated memory: Heap corruption detected. CTR detected the application wrote the memory after end of heap buffer.

```
char *ff (char *s){
    char *s1 = new char [strlen(s)];
    strcpy(s1, s);
    return s1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *s = new char [5];

    strcpy(s, "hello");
    char *s2 = ff(s);

    delete []s;     // This works normal
    delete []s2;    // But I get an error on that line
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously, this is just an exercise and in a real setting you would be using `std::string` instead, right ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Absolutely right. I'm not allowed to use std::string;

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
char *s = new char [5];
strcpy(s, "hello");
```

Causes **Undefined behavior(UB)**.
You are writing beyond the bounds of allocated memery. You allocated enough memory for `5` characters but your string has `6` characters including the `\0`.

Once your program has caused this UB, all bets are off and any behavior is possible.

You need:

```
char *s = new char [strlen("hello") + 1];
```

In fact the **ideal solution is to use `std::string` and not `char *`**. These are precisley the mistakes which `std::string` avoids. And there is no real need of using `char *` instead of `std::string` in your example.
With `std::string`:

- You don't need to `new` anything
- You don't need to `delete` anything &
- You can do everything with `std::string`, that you do with `char *`.

Comment: Agreed that using `std::string` is the best approach. One other way of writing the improved `new` allocation midway through your answer would be `char *s = new char[sizeof("hello")]`, avoiding the call to `strlen()` at runtime (although a smart compiler could possibly optimize it out). That obviously only works if you have a constant string, though, which probably isn't the common case.

Answer (score 13):

`new char [strlen(s)];` does not count the closing `\0` character, so your buffer is too short by one character.

Answer (score 9):

`strcpy` includes the null terminator; `strlen` does not.  Write:

```
char *s1 = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
```

Answer (score 6):

From man [strcpy(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

> The  strcpy()  function  copies the string pointed to by src,
>   **including the terminating null byte ('\0')**, to the buffer  pointed  to
>   by  dest.

So you need to reserve `6` bytes `5` for the string and `1` for the `NULL` byte

```
char *s = new char [6];
strcpy(s, "hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

All answers so far have addressed either the first or the second allocation. To sum up, there are *two* changes you must make:

```
char *s1 = new char [strlen(s) + 1];
...
char *s = new char [5 + 1];
```

In both cases, you must allocate enough space for the string **plus one byte for the terminating '\0'**.

As others already pointed out, with c++ it's easier and safer to use `std::string`. No fuss with allocation and release of memory or paying attention to '\0' bytes:

```
std::string ff (const std::string &s){
    std::string s1(s);
    // do something else with s1
    return s1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string s("hello");
    std::string s2 = ff(s);
    return 0;
}
```

and if it's just copying the string:

```
std::string s("hello");
std::string s2(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `char *s1 = new char [strlen(s) + 1];` to make room for the `'\0'` which terminates the string.

Answer (score 1):

You've corrupted s2 pointer by

```
strcpy(s, "hello");
```

Because s has size 5, while you've missed that strcpy includes string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial string `s` is only five characters long so can't be null terminated. `"hello"` will be copied by `strcpy` including the null-terminator but you'll have overrun the buffer. The `strlen` needs it to be null terminated so if the null's not there, you'll have problems. Try changing this line:

char *s = new char [6];

Better still, prefer `std::string` to C style string functions - they're just as efficient and a lot safer and easier to use. Also, try to avoid `new` and `delete` unless you really have to use them. The problems you're getting are very common and can easily be avoided.