# Lost connection to MySQL server when deleting initid->ptr, MySQL aggregate function (UDF)

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-udf

I created a MySQL aggregate UDF in C++.
I am returning `char*` from the final function of MySQL aggregate UDF.
In the `void xxx_deinit(UDF_INIT initid)` I am releasing any memory used by my function.
I am releasing the memory by deleting the `init->ptr`.

My deinit function:

```
extern "C" void xxx_deinit(UDF_INIT * initid)
{
    delete initid->ptr;
}
```

In the init function I am initialing the `ptr` like this:

```
extern "C" bool xxx_init(UDF_INIT * initid, UDF_ARGS * args, char* message)
{
    const char*  demo = "demo";

    initid->ptr = (char*) demo;

    return 0;
}
```

I am able to create the UDF and install it in the MySQL server.
After installing when I try to call the function, an error message pops up like this:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

But when I delete the line: `delete initid->ptr;` from the `xxx_deinit(UDF_INIT * initid)` function, I get the desired output.
But I am guessing this is the wrong approach because it will lead to a memory leak.
Also, the same statement: `delete initid->ptr;` doesn't generate error in case of simple UDF of return type `char*`.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
Any kind of help or suggestions will be of great help.
thanks in advance.

Can anyone help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no memory leak, as `"demo"` is a pointer to static memory.

You are trying to `delete` a pointer to memory that was not allocated with `new`. Your runtime has every right to blow up.

The simplest solution is to simply remove the `delete` in your deinit function. If you will always put a static string there, that is sufficient.

Alternatively, you can switch to dynamic allocation for the  memory of the `ptr` member. In the init function:

```
initid->ptr = strdup("demo");
```

In the deinit function:

```
free(initid->ptr);
```

Note that we use `free` instead of `delete`, as `strdup` allocates memory using `malloc`. Never cross `new/delete` and `malloc/free`!

Comment: so what do you suggest i should do?

Comment: can you suggest me something, please?

Comment: Added two ways forward to my answer.

Comment: Tried what? Did you attach a debugger? Where does it crash?

Comment: I tried using `strdup("demo")` as you mentioned above, it didn't work.
I am building my code into a dll file so it builds fine but crashes when I try to call the function, which causes MySQL server crash also. It crashes in `free(initid->ptr)` only. @Botje

Comment: You should attach a debugger and show a stack trace. I just reviewed the [MySQL UDF documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-udf.html) and you are using `initid->ptr` correctly. Is it possible the actual implementation of your UDF is doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried something and it worked. I added a line of code `initid->ptr = nullptr;` before `delete initid->ptr;` and now I am get my required output. Is it the right way to do this? @Botje

Comment: No, that is an explicit memory leak. You threw away the only reference to allocated memory.

Comment: But that's the only thing that works, other than that nothing works.@Botje

Comment: I tried with `new` also, as described in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247126/c-new-delete-and-char but that also didn't work @Botje

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222392/discussion-between-sahil-verma-and-botje).